# Having different body styles while using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Jquerymobile does some really cool things to make page loads really fast, such as simply loading the content on a new page.

I've created however some custom styles for the body tag which I include in the header, for example:

```
<body class="<? echo $page;?>">
```

Depending on the page, I'm inserting a different class, which loads up a different background to keep things interesting.

If I click a link however to go to this new page it seems I don't see this class in effect until I refresh the whole page and its forced to reload everything.

The question is, how can I make it so that on clicking the link it will actually apply this class? I'm wondering if I need to make it so that the buttons actually add the class to the body, ie:

```
$('insert-button-name').click(function(){

    $('body').addClass('insert-page-class');

});
```

I guess I'm trying to find out what is the appropriate way to do this while staying within compatibility of the mobile phone way of doing things. I know the jquery I have done there will work for regular browsers.

Cheers

Comment: You probably need to refresh the jQM look and feel, try chaining .trigger('create'); to the page

Comment: I think so. Any further pointers on how to chain trigger('create') to the page?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RwHWC/1/ just an example of chaining the trigger()

Comment: That actually worked. The only problem now is if I hit a back button how do I tell the page to trigger('create') again and re-add the classes I just removed?

Answer (score 1):

Simply specify an id for each of the data-role="page".  Then, in your CSS,  simply specify rules like...

```
#home{  background-color:#FF0000; }
#login{ background-color:#00FF00; }
```

This gives you a central, non-programmatic, hot-swappable, and cacheable way to manage your color changes.  DOM manipulation is expensive from a performance perspective so this will also be a faster solution

Comment: Thanks for that, while that would work if I was just restyling the objects inside the body, I'm actually applying different styles to the <body> object itself. So even though it may not be the most efficient, simply applying new rules to the body tag doesn't work and a refresh of the page is essential.